# how to implement generic c++ for configuring feature?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I'm building a generic feature configuration. I'm planing to define feature structure as below.

```
#define DEFINE_FEATURE(NAME) struct Feature##NAME {};
```

and I can define a bunch of them as :

```
DEFINE_FEATURE(A)
DEFINE_FEATURE(B)
DEFINE_FEATURE(C)
```

How do I implement a generic class that I can use to define a various feature combination? And it holds all features.

```
#define DEFINE_CONFIG(NAME, FeatureA,...) \ 
auto config_##NAME = Config::create().set_feature(FeatureA{}).set_feature(FeatureB).set_feature(....)()
```

For example, I define new/old product configuration as

```
DEFINE_CONFIG(NewProduct, FeatureA, FeatureB, FeatureC);
DEFINE_CONFIG(OldProduct, FeatureA);
```

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like an XY problem.

Comment: if this is c++11 or higher, suggest using a constexpr int containing bits. Much easier.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a std::tuple specialisation as the option collection.

```
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>


// does some list of type contain type Seek?
template<class Seek, class...Ts>
struct tuple_contains;

// specialise for empty list (false)
template<class Seek> struct tuple_contains<Seek> : std::false_type {};

// specialise for first type == Seek    
template<class Seek, class...Rest>
struct tuple_contains<Seek, Seek, Rest...> : std::true_type {};

// lower priority for all other cases (less specialised)
template<class Seek, class This, class...Rest>
struct tuple_contains<Seek, This, Rest...> : tuple_contains<Seek, Rest...> {};

// special case for tuple. This should probably have a different name.    
template<class Seek, class...Ts>
struct tuple_contains<Seek, std::tuple<Ts...>> : tuple_contains<Seek, Ts...> {};

// some options
struct CoolOption1 {};
struct CoolOption2 {};
struct CoolOption3 {};

// our current option set    
using CurrentOptions = std::tuple<CoolOption1, CoolOption3>;

// tests
int main()
{
    constexpr bool hasopt1 = tuple_contains<CoolOption1, CurrentOptions>();
    constexpr bool hasopt2 = tuple_contains<CoolOption2, CurrentOptions>();
    constexpr bool hasopt3 = tuple_contains<CoolOption3, CurrentOptions>();

    static_assert(hasopt1 == true);
    static_assert(hasopt2 == false);
    static_assert(hasopt3 == true);
}
```

Note: if you can, I would avoid preprocessor macros. Once they start appearing in header files your code becomes tightly coupled to the global namespace. This makes writing tests or re-using code in other projects more problematic.